# Collect a Stream of objects into a Map

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a csv file of user details which I will have to load into a HashMap by reading each line. This is done using a little help from Java 8 streams.

```
 Map<String,MockUser> users = new HashMap<>();
 try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()))) {
            stream.forEach(s -> {
                String[] fields = s.split(",");
                MockUser user = new MockUser(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]);
                users.put(user.getUsername(), user);
            });    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


private class MockUser {
        String username;
        String password;
        String role;

        MockUser(String username, String password, String role) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.role = role;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getRole() {
            return role;
        }

        public void setRole(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }
    }
```

This works well. However, I had to write a 3 line code to split and add the stream results into a map. I tried using `Stream.collect` , But I quite cant get this thing right?

Is there a way I can simplify the above code using `Stream.collect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally came to an understanding that `Collectors.GroupingBy` should not be used for converting stream into a map. Because this would group similar results in a list and give it back as a `Map<String,List<T>>`. What I wanted was a `Map<String,T>`.

After skimming through the Javadocs, I found `Collectors.toMap` which is the exact solution I was looking for.

The below is the code that I ended up writing.

```
users = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()))
                    .map(line -> line.split(","))
                    .map(fields -> new MockUser(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            MockUser::getUsername,
                            user -> user));
```

Comment: This code only works if the username is unique among all mock users, otherwise it fails with an exception. Are you sure it fits your use case? This is why `groupingBy` creates a `Map<key, List>`, so that elements with the same key are grouped in a list.

Comment: Works for my case. the user file should not have any duplicates anyways... An exception is expected if the file contains duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
Map<String, MockUser> users = Files.lines(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()))
                               .map(line -> line.split(","))
                               .map(fields -> new MockUser(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]))
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MockUser::getUserName))
```

Comment: This however wants the MockUser::getUserName to be static... Any idea why? BTW MockUser is a POJO and i want that stay that way

Comment: It is a method reference, has nothing to do with it being static or not, not sure why it gives you the error

Comment: This answer didnt work. The collection at the end I was getting was a `Map<String,List>`
This was the error I got.
`Error:(52, 29) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<com.raja.lambda.UserFileTest.MockUser>>
    upper bounds: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,com.raja.lambda.UserFileTest.MockUser>,java.lang.Object`

Comment: Apparently groupingBy groups similar keys into a list and provides a <key,List> pair. I had to use Collectors.toMap(). See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that

Answer (score -1):

Try [Collectors.groupingBy](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/) it's a helper method that turn stream to a map just exactly what you do.

Comment: Apparently groupingBy groups similar keys into a list and provides a <key,List> pair. I had to use Collectors.toMap(). See my answer.